# Flutter - Provider - How to change UI based on value from Provider?

Tags: firebase, flutter, conditional-statements, provider

I want to have two forms of the UI based on an object value that I get from a Stream Provider.

In the widget, I get the object like this:

```
final recentPostData = Provider.of<List<RecentPostData>>(context) ?? [];
```

Then, I want to change the UI based on an attribute of RecentPostData:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(children: [
        (recentPostData[0].attribute != '123') ?
          RaisedButton( ... )
        : SizedBox( ... ),
```

The problem: There is a delay of the stream value coming in, thus I get the initial error:
"RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0"

I tried to therefore use multiple conditions - hence check first (recentPostData != []) and then check for the second condition, but this did not work (got the same error).

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance!

```
class _PostFeedState extends State<PostFeed> {

  bool isLoading = false; // track if products fetching

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  var recentPostData = Provider.of<List<RecentPostData>>(context) ?? [];

  getProducts() async {  
    if (!hasMore) {  
      print('No More Products');  
      return;  
    }  
    if (isLoading) {  
      return;  
    }  
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true; 
    });  
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;  
    if (lastDocument == null) {  
      querySnapshot = await firestore
        .collection('posts')  
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)  
        .limit(documentLimit)  
        .getDocuments();  
      print(0);
    } else {  
      querySnapshot = await firestore  
        .collection('posts')  
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)  
        .startAfterDocument(lastDocument)  
        .limit(documentLimit)  
        .getDocuments();  
      print(1);  
    }  
    if (querySnapshot.documents.length < documentLimit) {  
      hasMore = false;  
    }
    if (querySnapshot.documents.length == 0) {
      setState(() {
        hasMore = false;
        isLoading = false;
      }); 

      return;
    } 
    lastDocument = querySnapshot.documents[querySnapshot.documents.length - 1];  
    products.addAll(querySnapshot.documents);  
    setState(() {  
      isLoading = false;  
    });  
  }

  if (init) {
    getProducts();
    setState(() {
      init = false;
    });
  }

  void loadNewPosts() {
    setState(() {
        products = [];
        lastDocument = null;
      });
    getProducts();
  }

  return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(children: [
        (recentPostData != []) ? (recentPostData[0].pid != DatabaseServicePosts().postDataFromSnapshot(products[0]).pid) ?
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              loadNewPosts();
              setState(() {
                hasNew = false;
              });
            },
            child: Text('New Posts Available'),
            color: Colors.green[300],
          )
        : SizedBox(height: 0) : SizedBox(height: 0),
        products.length == 0  
          ? Center(  
            child: Text('No Data...'),
          ) :
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            ...products.map((el) => PostTile (postData: DatabaseServicePosts().postDataFromSnapshot(el))),
          ],),
        (hasMore && !init) ?
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              getProducts();
            },
            child: Text(
              'More Posts',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            color: Colors.lightBlue[200],
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(102.0),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey[400])
            ),
          )
          : Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Container(child: Text('No more Posts')),
          ),
        isLoading  
          ? Container(  
              child: Text('Loading'),  
            )  
          : Container(),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
      ]  
    ),
  ); 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think before building widget checking size of recentPostData can solve your issue. Following code may help You.

```
recentPostData.length > 0 ? (recentPostData[0].attribute != '123') ?
          RaisedButton( ... )
        : SizedBox( ... ) : Text(" show Loading indicator")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It's another way of doing the two conditions I mentioned above. What do you mean with before building?

Comment: I mean there only. Where you are doing it. What happen when you apply my solution? Did it work ?

Comment: I tried your solution, but got the same error. The problem seems to be that even if recentPostData.length > 0 is wrong, Flutter still reads the code that comes after it and thus, gives me the error. I run the code wihtin the build method because the provider.of method needs the (context) of the build method, no?

Comment: after getting error data is display or not?  Provider.of<List<RecentPostData>>(context).value here you are missing value? as you mention you are getting data from stream, so are you calling any method to get data? and of you are calling then where? if you are calling in build method it self then streambuilder could be best solution.

Comment: Yes it displays the data afterwards. It's a milisecond when you can see the error then everything is normal. The reason is that when I stream the data it takes a bit of time to come in. And the code already runs through and gets to the point where it searches for an array at recentPostData[0]... The first time the code runs through the data is not yet there and recentPD is just []. Hence it gives me the error. Then after some time the value comes in and recentPD[0] gives a result and the code works. Makes sense?

Comment: can you please add code that why your code takes time to load. please add all the possible code related to this situation, so i can understand whole situation.

Comment: I added the whole code above. Thanks for your support here - I really appreciate this! I have been stuck on this problem for hours now and cannot find a solution. At the end of the code you can see the place where the problem occurs. It's basically running through all if statements even though it hasn't received the provider.of value yet.

Comment: var recentPostData = Provider.of<List<RecentPostData>>(context).value  ?? []; Are you missing .value over there?